# Confusion Matrices in Orange

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, orange, confusion-matrix

I'm using cross-validation to evaluate the performance of the classification algorithms in orange, but I have some doubts with respect to the confusion matrices:

- How can I store the confusion matrix associated to each fold of the cross-validation?

> ```
> result = orngTest.crossValidation(classifier, table, 5, randseed = 1)
> cm = orngStat.confusionMatrices(result)[0]
> ```

Above you can see part of my code. As I understood from the documentation the object confusionMatrices should have 5 differents confusion matrices, but thats not true 'cause I check that and only have one object stored.

Can anyone explain me how to get the 5 matrices?
And just in case that is not possible, could you explain how is the confusion matrix that I getting at the end of the process calculated ?

PD. By the way this was implemented with orange 2.7.8

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [Orange.evaluation.scoring.confusion_matrices](http://docs.orange.biolab.si/reference/rst/Orange.evaluation.scoring.html#Orange.evaluation.scoring.confusion_matrices)
2. It returns a list of confusion matrices one for every classifier for which the
   evaluation results were computed (in your case `len(classifier) == len(cm)`).
3. The confusion matrix for every classifier is an simple aggregate of classifier
   results evaluated over the folds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you tell me which aggregation function is used?